# Complex order by in MySQL for comments

Tags: mysql

I have a post with multiple comments at the bottom.

Some comments are direct replies to that post, some are replies to other comments, and some are **Replies to Replies**. (think of any post on Facebook - same structure).

```
id   |   comment   |  reply_to_level1  |  reply_to_level2  |

1    |    1 comm   |          0        |         0         | 
2    |    2 comm   |          0        |         0         |
4    |   1.1 comm  |          1        |         0         |
5    |   1.2 comm  |          1        |         0         |
6    |  1.1.1 comm |          1        |         4         |
```

I need to sort them out like this:

```
1    |    2 comm   |  
2    |    1 comm   |
3    |   1.1 comm  |
4    |  1.1.1 comm |
5    |   1.2 comm  |
```

What I have so far is this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `comment` ORDER BY CASE WHEN `reply_to` = 0 THEN `id` ELSE `reply_to` end DESC
```

... but it gives me the following:

```
1    |    2 comm   |  
2    |    1 comm   |
3    |   1.1 comm  |
4    |   1.2 comm  |
5    |  1.1.1 comm |
```

I can't figure out how to put message `1.1.1` right after `1.1` and before `1.2`. (Reply to Reply is not in the right place).

The reason I got `reply_to_level1` and `reply_to_level2` is to differentiate replies to main comments and **replies to replies**. As you can see `1.1.1` is a reply to `4` under comment `1`. I've done it just hoping that I can use those levels in SQL statements to get desired results.

If anyone can help me please...

Comment: You cannot sort multilevel hierarchy data with single expression. Make recursive CTE which calculates fully qualified comment path (normalize ID with leading zeros) and use it for sorting purposes.

Comment: Ok. Can you please show an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+sort+hierarchical+data